# About Amster '--body' option (OpenAM command line)

Tags: json, command-line, terminal, openam

There is a '--body' option for most of the Amster commands. This options allows you to send the body of a request with JSON syntax. However, if the body of your request is big, the --body option will be big and the Amster command will be huge for your terminal. Is there any option to specify this JSON text in a way that it is not so uncomfortable for the command-line?
Maybe it exists an option that allows you to indicate the path of a JSON file or something like that.
I will be very grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer below is based on the latest available Amster (6.0.0)

You can use Amster in [Script mode](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/amster/6/user-guide/#sec-usage-scripts). 
Essentially you can write your amster commands in a separate file, lets call it `myscript.amster`, please note, the extension is not important.

You can then add your entire command including the json in your script, for e.x. to create a realm: Please note the use of: <kbd>\</kbd> to spill the json across multiple lines.

```
create Realms --global --body '{ \
    "name": "test", \
    "active": false, \
    "parentPath": "/", \
    "aliases": [ "testing" ] \
}'
```

Now, you can run this script in two modes:

From within the amster shell:

```
am> :load <pathToYourScript>
```

Without having to enter the script mode:

```
amster/amster <pathToYourScript>
```

In this mode, do remember to `connect` to your openam server before running your commands and `:quit` at the end. You should find some more samples in the `samples` directory of your amster.